# Do I need glib (OSX)?

Tags: osx

One of the options when installing emacs in OSX (through homebrew) is support for glib.  It's not included by default.  What does it buy me to install?  Any downsides?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I don't think you need glib.

According to `brew cat emacs`, the `--glib` option actually means `--with-file-notification=gfile`, and run `./configure --help` inside Emacs source root directory tells:

```
--with-file-notification=LIB
                      use a file notification library (LIB one of: yes,
                      inotify, kqueue, gfile, w32, no)
```

In my experience, `kqueue` is used on OSX by default (as long as you don't set the option by yourself).